# Is it possible to not use backticks for html in web components?

Tags: web-component

Been playing around with web components but one annoyance is that the editor ignored syntax highlighting etc because the html string is between backticks:

Ie: this.innerHTML = ‘…'

Is there other to actually expose html to a web component without using raw strings?

Answer (score 0):

The Lit plugin does the job for template literal Strings (and you do not have to use Lit)

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=runem.lit-plugin

or

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bashmish.es6-string-css

or

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pushqrdx.inline-html

I do have some cases where it is better to use `/*html*/` instead of `/*css*/` **YMMV**

Comment: I'm looking to not use any libraries...pure vanilla js

Comment: Are you using an Editor but not using any extra features of the editor. Man, that's what we did 25 years ago in Notepad.

Comment: I have vs code. and prettier. it ignores the code inbetween backticks.

Comment: Yes, if you are a Prettier-Purist and do not want to install plugins that Fix Prettier Failures, you have to deal with un-highlighted Template Literal Strings.

Comment: Are you talking about installing the Lit plugin for vscode? If that's the case I can do that. I thought you were telling me use Lit in my code.

Comment: Read, I wrote: _and you do not have to use Lit_

Comment: I installed it, but how do I run it? Nothing happens if I click "save"

Comment: You don't "Run" Plugins in VSCode, they Run when required. place a comment **before** your Template Literal String: /*html*/`..yourlitstring..` Also see the 2 alternative plugins I mentioned

Comment: yeah i tried all three, nothing happens. I dont' want to document the strings as they contain a mix of css and html.

Comment: They all work on all my classroom workstations. <signing-off>